# Is the $n$-th prime smaller than $n(\log n + \log\log n-1+\frac{\log\log n}{\log n})$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p_n$ be the $n$-th prime. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) gives the following known bounds on $p_n/n$ when $n\geq6$:
$$ \log n+\log\log n-1 \leq \frac{p_n}{n} \leq \log n+\log\log n. $$

If I take the first few terms in the asymptotic expansion for $p_n/n$, like so:
$$ \frac{p_n}{n} = \log n+\log\log n-1+\frac{\log\log n}{\log n} - \frac{2}{\log n} +  O\left(\frac{(\log\log n)^2}{\log^2 n}\right), $$
it follows that
$$ \frac{p_n}{n} < \log n+\log\log n-1+\frac{\log\log n}{\log n} + \frac{c}{\log n}, $$
for $c>-2$ and large enough $n$. For at least those $n$ that I've checked however ($p_n\leq 10^{11}$), I find that this inequality holds with $c=0$ and $p_n>347$, and also with $c=-1$ and $p_n > 5393$.

Is this actually correct?

Is there a sharper inequality?

Comment: As a general warning, $10^{10}$ is a relatively small number in regards to conjectures like these.

Comment: Fair enough, I just ran out of memory.

Comment: A recent paper : de Reyna and Jeremy ['The n-th prime asymptotically'](http://arxiv.org/abs/1203.5413).

Comment: @RaymondManzoni Thank you. I followed their reference to http://arxiv.org/abs/1002.0442, a paper by Pierre Dusart, which has the desired inequality on page 2. Can you submit your comment as an answer, mentioning the Dusart paper, so that I can accept it?

Comment: I am Glad the link was useful @Kirill and provided an answer (I didn't know then that Dusart's fine work was exactly the answer you wanted since it was 2am here...).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While examining de Reyna's work about Riemann's zeros I noticed his recent paper with Jeremy ['The n-th prime asymptotically'](http://arxiv.org/abs/1203.5413) and thought it could help you (without having the time to elaborate...).

Knowing more zeta zeros allowed indeed Pierre Dusart in his $1998$ thesis to update Rosser and Schoenfeld's earlier results and get [new bounds on $\pi(x)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Bounds_on_the_prime-counting_function) (other results are [here](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me_des_nombres_premiers#Histoire) in french).

He extended his results to bounds for $p_n$ in his $1999$ paper ['The Kth prime is greater than k(ln(k)+ln(ln(k))-1) for k>=2'](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2585122) and in $2010$ in the paper you found ['Estimates of Some Functions Over Primes without R.H.'](http://arxiv.org/abs/1002.0442) and which contains indeed the precise :
$$\frac{p_n}n\le\ln(n)+\ln(\ln(n))-1+\frac{\ln(\ln(n))-2}{\ln(n)}\quad\text{for}\ n\ge 688383,$$
$$\frac{p_n}n\ge\ln(n)+\ln(\ln(n))-1+\frac{\ln(\ln(n))-21/10}{\ln(n)}\quad\text{for}\ n\ge 3.$$