# Why is $p_n\sim\sum_{k=1}^{n}\log(p_k)$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Why is

$$
p_n\sim\sum_{k=1}^{n}\log(p_k)
$$

where $p_n$ is the $n$th prime?

In addition, is it true that

$$
n\log\left(\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}\log(k)}{\log(\log(n))}\right)
$$

is a better approximation for $p_n$ than $n\log(n)$?

Comment: Isn't it true for non-prime numbers as well?

Comment: $p_n \sim n\log n$, so $\log p_k \sim \log k$, and $\sum_{k=1}^n \log k \sim n\log n$.

Comment: Seems to me that if it is true for all $P_n$ primes, then it has to be true at least for their "neighbors".

Comment: @DanielFischer Wouldn't $\log p_k \sim k\log k$ instead of just $\log k$?

Comment: @DarthGeek $\log p_k \approx \log (k\log k) = \log k + \log \log k$, and the $\log\log k$ term is asymptotically negligible.

Comment: Is it licit to sum equivalents ? In my memory it is not obviously true...

Comment: @D.L. please elaborate

Comment: Why if $u_n\simeq v_n$ and $u'_n\simeq w_n$, $u_n+u'_n\simeq v_n+w_n$ ?  (I don't find the good command sorry...)

Comment: More accurate, why do we have $\sum_{k=1}^n p_k \simeq \sum_{k=1}^n log(k)$ ?

Comment: Sorry, I have understood my problem. The point is that the sum of equivalents is licit in this case because it is the partial sum of a nonconvergent infinite sum, so there's no problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a quick qualitative answer, we note that by the prime number theorem $p_k \sim k\log k$, and hence we have $\log p_k \sim \log k + \log \log k \sim \log k$, and

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \log k \sim n \log n.$$

One has to do some work, however, to see that the summation of asymptotically equal terms leads in this case to asymptotically equal sums.

Probably more instructive is a summation by parts,

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n \log p_k &= \sum_{m \leqslant p_n} \left(\pi(m) - \pi(m-1)\right)\log m\\
&= \pi(p_n)\log p_n - \sum_{m\leqslant p_n} \pi(m)\left(\log (m+1) - \log m\right)\\
&= n\log p_n - \sum_{m\leqslant p_n} \pi(m) \left(\frac{1}{m} + O\left(m^{-2}\right)\right)\\
&= n\log p_n - \sum_{m\leqslant p_n} \frac{\pi(m)}{m} + O(\log\log p_n)\\
&= n\log p_n + O\left(\frac{p_n}{\log p_n}\right),
\end{align}$$

and the prime number theorem says that $n\log p_n \sim p_n$.

Regarding the addition, [Raymond Manzoni](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/21783/raymond-manzoni) reports in [his answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/435195/83702) to [a question on bounds for $p_n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/434229/is-the-n-th-prime-smaller-than-n-log-n-log-log-n-1-frac-log-log-n-log) that Pierre Dusart proved that

$$\begin{align}
\frac{p_n}n &\leqslant \log n+\log (\log n) -1+\frac{\log (\log n)-2}{\log n}\quad\text{for}\ n\geqslant 688383,\\
\frac{p_n}n &\geqslant\log n+\log (\log n)-1+\frac{\log (\log n)-21/10}{\log n}\quad\text{for}\ n\geqslant 3.
\end{align}$$

Since

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \log k = \int_1^n \log t\,dt + \sum_{k=2}^n \left(\log k - \int_{k-1}^k \log t\,dt\right) = n\log n - n + O(\log n),$$

we have

$$\begin{align}
\log \left(\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n \log k}{\log \log n}\right)
&= \log \left(\frac{n\log n - n + O(\log n)}{\log \log n}\right)\\
&= \log \left(n\frac{\log n - 1 + O\left(\frac{\log n}{n}\right)}{\log \log n}\right)\\
&= \log n + \log \left(\log n - 1 + O\left(\tfrac{\log n}{n}\right)\right) - \log \log \log n\\
&= \log n + \log \log n + O\left(\log \log \log n\right),
\end{align}$$

which means it is indeed a better approximation than $n\log n$. However, a still better approximation, at least for large $n$, is

$$p_n \approx n \log \left(\sum_{k=1}^n \log k\right)$$

without dividing the argument of the logarithm by $\log \log n$. Or the even more accurate $p_n \approx n(\log n + \log \log n - 1 + o(1))$ which is simple enough to remember even when one hasn't Dusart's bounds handy to look up.

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer - this is much clearer - again, many thanks

Comment: I only just saw the addition, I've added an answer to that too.

Comment: Great - thanks for the complete answer :)