# Is $p_n \sim \frac{5}{4}n\log(n) + \frac{1}{2}n + \frac{(p_1+\ldots+p_{n-1})}{n-1}$ a good approximation for the $n^\text{th}$ prime?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

If you plot the following function $$f(n) = \frac{(p_1+\ldots+p_{n})}{n} - \frac{(p_1+\ldots+p_{n-1})}{n-1}$$ you get a graph that is similar to $$f(x) = \frac{5}{4}\log(x) + \frac{1}{2}$$

From this we can state $$\frac{(p_1+\ldots+p_{n})}{n} - \frac{(p_1+\ldots+p_{n-1})}{n-1} \sim \frac{5}{4}\log(n) + \frac{1}{2}$$
$$(p_1+\ldots+p_{n}) - (p_1+\ldots+p_{n-1}) \sim \frac{5}{4}n\log(n) + \frac{1}{2}n$$
$$p_n \sim \frac{5}{4}n\log(n) + \frac{1}{2}n + \frac{(p_1+\ldots+p_{n-1})}{n-1}$$

Looking at the graph for $$\left|\frac{5}{4}n\log(n) + \frac{1}{2}n + \frac{(p_1+\ldots+p_{n-1})}{n-1} - p_n\right|$$ the maximum error seems to be $\log(n^2)^2$, which would be quite good for larger $n$'s (if it is indeed true)

Comment: [You are overestimating](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/434229/is-the-n-th-prime-smaller-than-n-log-n-log-log-n-1-frac-log-log-n-log), $p_n = n\log n + n\log \log n - n + o(n)$.

Comment: Please show us your graphs, or at least tell us the range of $n$ they span.  It's possible your approximation is reasonably good for $n$ "small," but as has been pointed out, it overestimates $p_n$ for large $n$.  (A minor side remark:  The running average of the primes is an increasing function of $n$, so there is no need for the absolute value sign in your formula defining $f(n)$.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, notation: $f(x)\sim g(x)$ means that
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1,
$$
and $f(x)\approx g(x)$ means that the two functions are 'approximately' equal (which doesn't have a hard and fast definition).

Lower-order terms disappear under $\sim,$ so asking if $p_n\sim \frac54 n\log n+\frac12n+\frac{p_1+\cdots+p_{n-1}}{n-1}$ is the same as asking if $p_n\sim \frac54 n\log n$ (as long as you already know that the latter terms are asymptotically smaller). As it happens this is false: $p_n\sim n\log n,$ and so for large enough $n$ your estimate will be about 25% too large.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I thought I could use the $\sim$ symbol as 'roughly approximates', but perhaps I could have better used the $\approx$ symbol, as you mentioned.