# Does the proportional error $n\ln(n)$ for the $n$th prime approach a non-zero limit?

Tags: prime-numbers

The following graph shows the proportional error of $n\ln(n)$ for the $n^{th}$ prime.

The proportional error appears to fall towards $0.1$, and not zero, when considering the first $n=10,000,000$ natural numbers.

1. Is this a correct conclusion, or is this a case of a very very slow asymptotic approach to zero?
2. Where can I find a proof of the non-zero limit?

In comparison, plots of the proportional error of $\frac{n}{ln(n)}$ and $\text{Li}(n)$ for the number of primes up to $n$, $\pi(n)$, do show it approaching zero more clearly.

[image]

Comment: If you take more terms of the asymptotic expansion [cf. e.g. here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/435195) into account, you can see that $$\frac{p_n}{n\log n} - 1 \sim \frac{\log \log n}{\log n}\,,$$ and that decreases rather slowly.

Comment: The $0.1$ relative error with your data might be related to Wikipedia's [Non-asymptotic bounds on the prime-counting function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Non-asymptotic_bounds_on_the_prime-counting_function) section which states Dusart proved in $2010$ that $\frac{x}{\log x-1} \lt \pi(x)$ for $x \geq 5393$, and $\pi(x) \lt \frac {x}{\log x-1.1}$ for $x \geq 60184$. The difference in denominators of $0.1$ matches the relative error you got. However, right after this in the Wikipedia article shows $1$ & $1.1$ become $1 - \epsilon$ & $1 + \epsilon$ for large enough $x$.